# Is Flutter http.MultipartRequest support boolean?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

In Flutter, I am using **http.MultipartRequest** for **POST** image and sending the payload into backend. Some of my payload is boolean but **http.MultipartRequest** didn't support boolean. How can I solve this problem?

This is my approach.

```
  String url,
  Map<String, dynamic> payload,
  File? imageFile,
) async {
  final chatReplyData =
      ChatReplyData(responseStatus: 0, validStatusCode: false);

  try {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse('${getApiPrefix()}$url'),
    );

    // Add image file to the request
    if (imageFile != null) {
      final imageStream = http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
      final imageLength = await imageFile.length();
      final multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
        'file',
        imageStream,
        imageLength,
        filename: imageFile.path,
      );
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
    }

    // Add other payload data
    payload.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      request.fields[key] = value.toString();
    });

    final response = await request.send();

    // get response as json string
    final responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    // Parse response as JSON
    final responseBody = jsonDecode(responseData);

    final responseStatus = response.statusCode;
    chatReplyData.responseStatus = responseStatus;

    debugPrint(
        'myLog: getChatReply -> url = $url, payload = $payload, imageFile = $imageFile');
    debugPrint(
        'myLog: getChatReply -> responseStatus = $responseStatus, responseBody = $responseBody');

    chatReplyData.message = responseBody?['message'];

    return chatReplyData;
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('myError: getChatReply -> error = $e');
    return chatReplyData;
  }
}
```

Here

```
payload.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      request.fields[key] = value.toString();
    });
```

I don't want to pass all fields as a **String**. Cause some of my value is **boolean**.

Comment: No. As you can find here. : https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html fields is type of Map<String,String> you can send boolean value as String

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to pass the boolean value as boolean. I don't want to convert it into String. Cause my backend API only take boolean value not String.
So, I am seeking, is there any solution exist or not.

Thanks for sharing the documentation.

Comment: Can you check that at backend  in which form they are getting that value  when you pass it from your end ?

Comment: Yes. I already check backend.

Comment: is that correct value ?

Comment: Yes. The value is correct. I can't change backend. I have to handle it from frontend. I can't send boolean and others value using multiparse. I have to pass data from multiparse then I have to convert it into string

Comment: Can you tell how they are saving value to backend when you send from app ?

Comment: I can't brother, cause this is handled by our backend developer. I just check the schema for this problem. They are maintaining data types into schema

Answer (score 0):

You try this method it will be working fine.

#API Definition

```
Future multipartRequest(
    url,
    payload,
    imageFile,
  ) async {
    String baseUrl = getBaseUrl();

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('$baseUrl$url'));
    request.fields.addAll(payload);

    if (imageFile.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var image in imageFile) {
        var file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('FileList', image);
        request.files.add(file);
      }
    }

    try {
      var response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return {
          "status": response.statusCode,
          "data": await response.stream.bytesToString()
        };
      } else {
        return {"status": response.statusCode, "data": response.reasonPhrase};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

#API Call

```
multipartRequest("endpoint url",
   {
          "payload1":"Something",
          "payload2":24,
          "payload3":false,

        },
        imagefiles);
```

Comment: When I try to write this code
```request.fields.addAll(payload);```
That type it gives me error. I have to pass the payload Map as a String